# how to prevent browser from writing log in the console?

Tags: javascript, logging, websocket, signalr, console.log

I am creating a simple chat app using SignalR. But the problem is if I open the console on my browser, I can see which port it is connected to, message transmission information and other logs. I want to prevent browsers from writing these information. How can I do this?

[Example: WhatsApp. We can't see anything if we open the console while browsing WhatsApp's web portal.]

Comment: BTW, there is no way to hide port and IP from the user.

Comment: On a side note: since you're mentioning opening the browser console and wanting to hide something there, I'm guessing you're not thinking about regular users, but users who would like to fiddle around with your site. But even if nothing is logged, they'll be able to see everything that's going on in the network tab

Comment: is there any efficient way to use ports to prevent end users to copy the port URL and tryout that in other places?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can redefine `window.console`:

```
window.console = {
    log: ()=>{}, info: ()=>{}, error: ()=>{}, warn: ()=>{}//etc
}
```

Comment: I am very new. Where should I put this?

Comment: @MahmudulHasan In the first line of your JavaScript file.